# How can battery usage of Android be at 79%?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery-life

Till last night everything was kinda balanced.....most of the different parts of the usage were in between 20-35 %, but this morning after having activated the internet from my network provider, it all got unbalanced.

Now Android usage is at 79% and the rest of the things are at a very low usage (between 3 and 7%).

What can be causing this? GPS is off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **total** of all the usage should always approximate 100%. That Android (the core) is responsible for 79% of the entire drain isn't anything to worry about, it just says that not much else was drawing power.